# Get column values of the updated row

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

```
$query = "UPDATE transaction SET c_status = :status WHERE c_name = :name AND c_id = :id";

$stmt = $this->handle->prepare($query);

$stmt->bindParam(':c_status',$status,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':c_name',$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':c_id',$id,PDO::PARAM_STR);

return $stmt->execute();
```

Using the above syntax, I am able to update a record in the `transaction` table. However, what I only get with the return is a boolean. I want to know if there is a way I can get the `transaction_id` (**the `AUTO_INCREMENT` field in the `transaction` table, `c_id` and `c_name` where just a column of that**) and the rest of its columns?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - What if I won't opt to stored procedure approach? Will that limit me not to be able to do this?

Comment: With MySQL, you'll have to do an extra select, so either you need to do it manually or using a stored procedure to do it all in one call.

Answer (score 3):

This question is not related to PDO but to mysql in general.

UPDATE queries are not intended to return anything. To get a row from database you have to use SELECT query.

Comment: To be fair though, many RDBMS support something like this, PostgreSQL supports `UPDATE ... RETURNING` and SQL Server supports `UPDATE ... OUTPUT`. MySQL does not.

Comment: +1  I would add that you're better off declaring **c_name** as unique and possibly adding a **c_count** column if you need to.  Then you can select against the strings just inserted and reliably retrieve the **c_id** s.  Although possibly that might let you dispense with the ids altogether.